# How can I read user defined objects from a file?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object, bufferedreader

I am using BufferedReader to read Word objects from a file, but it turns out BufferedReader is designed so that it can only read in Strings, instead of a user defined object.

A Word object in this case is a string, just not defined as a String

In other words, how can I convert str2[i] into a Word object from a String in order to enqueue it?

This is because the enqueue method takes in Word objects.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    WordPriorityQueue x = new WordPriorityQueue();
    File file = new File("file goes here");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String st;
    while((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String str1 = br.readLine();
            String str2[] = str1.split(" ", 500);
            int i = 0;
            while(str2[i] != null) {
                //How can I convert the string str2[i] to a Word object?
                x.enqueue(str2[i]);  //Doesn't work for Strings
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't use a `BufferedReader`. I'm not sure what a "Word" object is, but to read binary data you use `InputStream`, and to read Java-serialized objects, you wrap them with `ObjectInputStream`. But please [edit] the question and explain what Word objects are.

Comment: Or maybe you just need to construct a Word from a String. Something like `new Word(string)`. But since we have no idea of what the class Word is, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you are using the `javax.speech.Word` object. I suppose that Word is a your class.

To create a new object, Java provides constructors.

> **Def**
>
> A *constructor* in Java is a special method that is used to initialize
>   objects. The constructor is called when an object of a class is
>   created.

So, in your code you have to create a Word Object using the constructor for each items.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //List that contains all words
    List<Word> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Create the scanner
    File file = new File("file goes here");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);    

    while( sc.hasNextLine() ) {
        String[] lineSplitted = sc.nextLine().split(" "); //add 500 as limit

        for (i=0; i<lineSplitted.length; i++) {
            //Call constructor
            wordsList.add(new Word(lineSplitted[i])                
        }
    }

    sc.close()
 }
```

In your Word class, add a constructor that as argument wants a string.

```
public class Word {

  private String word;

  public Word(String word) {
    this.word = word;
  }

  //Other methods, getter, setter, etc...
}
```

A the end, you will have a `java.util.List` of `Word` objects.